# C++ RAII interface to ROS?

Tags: c++, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a supported RAII interface to ROS?  i.e. a class that encapsulates the ros connection, with initialization in the constructor and teardown in the destructor, etc?

The tutorials all seem to start with a call to ros::init, for example, and I don't understand why that can't just be done in the NodeHandle constructor.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215435/c++-raii-interface-to-ros?/) by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2015-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So far, there is nothing (afaik). If often happens (at least for me) that you have several NodeHandels in a single Node. I have one for the global namespace and one local ( NodeHandle("~") ) so that it's a bit easier to see where a parameter comes from.

But the concept of a node lifecycle will probably end up in ROS 2:

https://github.com/gbiggs/design/commit/7aa6d337cdb66d51f7f29a4802bd635fa365adae

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2015-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on 2015-08-10**:
Thanks for the confirmation.... I thought that was the case.